# LevelDOWN: NODE_MODULE_VERSION error when testing, but not running

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, electron, leveldb

I have a `.npmrc` file with:

```
runtime = electron
target = 1.7.9
target_arch = x64
disturl = https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
build_from_source = true
```

And a`package.json` file with:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "mocha"
}
```

Following a `npm install`, when I run my node.js script using `npm start`, everything works as expected.  However, when I use `npm test` I'm running into an error:

`Uncaught LevelUPError: Failed to require LevelDOWN (The module '/Users/_me_/_project_/node_modules/leveldown/build/Release/leveldown.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 54. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using 'npm rebuild' or 'npm install').). Try 'npm install leveldown' if it's missing`

My `test.js` file uses a small subset of modules that do not require electron.

I've tried running `npm rebuild`, `npm install`, and `npm install leveldown` after clearing the `npm_modules` directory, but the error persists.

Any idea why I'm seeing these errors or how to correct this issue?

Edit:  I was able to switch mocha out with electron-mocha and bypass the error.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `node_modules` folder and reinstall everything?

Comment: @kontrollanten I have -- the error persists.  Yet, `npm start` doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. npm cache clean
2. npm install
3. electron-rebuild(need npm install electron-rebuild)

i ues these methods to solve the problem